# How to use two database in a single Project

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, mongodb, database

How can I have two database types in a single project?

I have made an IOS application in which I want to have two databases in it.
One, MySQL & the other MongoDB.

how to implement two database in a single application?
how can we exchange data between them.
i mean that if one implementation was in my sql & other implementation is in mongoDB.

Can somebody show me how I may achieve this.

Comment: Shouldn't you really just use one?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an adaptor layer for interfacing with DataSources, think `Webservices/RestAPIs`.
Once you have that then you can interface with `n` types of datasources.